# Dell S300 RAID controller: virtual disk failed

Tags: raid

I have a customer with Dell T310 server and this message stuck on the screen.
All hard drives are alive and showing up in `Configuration Utility`.
However, `No boot devices available`.

Most of the similar questions found in Google simply suggested to consider the data is lost and start rebuilding RAID from scratch and restore latest backup.

This didn't sound right, and I'm looking for an actual solution.

[image: error message]

Comment: I suspect the reason for the downvote is that you didn't actually ask a question. The info itself is good IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple hours spent, I was able to resolve the issue.

Since S300 is a software RAID, it truly relies on a Windows Driver to perform any operations, including "Rebuilding RAID" and removing "Failed" state to make the virtual drive bootable again.

I followed these steps to get the server backup and running:

- Boot from `Windows Server installation media`.
- During the installation no hard drives will be found.
- Choose to Load `S300 driver` (you need to download appropriate driver
  from Dell's website) and put it on a flash drive.
- One the driver is loaded, you will see your logical drives in the
  list.
- At this point you can cancel installation and reboot. Virtual disk is
  now unlocked and bootable again.